# Dagger 2 issue: cannot be provided without a @Provides method

Tags: android, dagger-2

I was playing around Dagger 2 in my project and then I got stuck at this error compilation. 
-> `Error:(18, 21) error: ....MyManager cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
...MyManager is injected at
...SignInPresenter.<init>(myManager)
...SignInPresenter is provided at
...SignInComponent.signInPresenter()`

I tried to research on the topic but I couldn't exactly point out the mistake in my code. I think I have made a small mistake somewhere or I understood something wrong in Dagger2. If anyone can point out the mistake. I will really appreciate it.

**My Manager**

```
public interface MyManager {
    Observable<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

**SignIn Presenter**

```
 @Inject
    public SignInPresenter(MyManager myManager) {
        this.myManager= myManager;
    }
```

I do something like this in **MySignInFragment**

```
   @Override protected void injectDependencies() {
        signInComponent = DaggerSignInComponent.builder()
                .myApplicationComponent(MyDaggerApplication.getMyComponents())
               .build();
    }
```

**SignIn Component**

```
@Component(modules = {MyModule.class},
        dependencies = {MyApplicationComponent.class})
public interface SignInComponent {
    SignInPresenter signInPresenter();
}
```

**This is my Application**

```
public class MyDaggerApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplicationComponent myApplicationComponent;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        myApplicationComponent = DaggerMyApplicationComponent.create();
        myApplicationComponent = DaggerMyApplicationComponent.builder().myModule(new MyModule(this)).build();
        myApplicationComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public MyApplicationComponent getMyAppComponents(){
        return myApplicationComponent;
    }

    public static MyApplicationComponent getMyComponents(){
        return myApplicationComponent;
    }
}
```

**My Module and Component Classes**

```
@Component(modules = {MyModule.class})
public interface MyApplicationComponent {
    void inject(MyDaggerApplication myDaggerApplication);
}

@Module
public class MyModule {
    private final MyDaggerApplication myDaggerApplication;

    public MyModule(MyDaggerApplication myDaggerApplication){
        this.myDaggerApplication = myDaggerApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context providesApplicationContext() {
        return this.myDaggerApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("My_Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public MyDefaultManager providesMyDefaultManager(MyDefaultManager myDefaultManager,Context context){
        return myDefaultManager.getInstance(context);
    }
}
```

I am guessing that I am doing something wrong in the `DaggerApplication`. Any suggestions advices will be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `MyDefaultManager` implements `MyManager`, change the final provider in `MyModule` to:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public MyManager providesMyDefaultManager(MyDefaultManager myDefaultManager,Context context){
    return myDefaultManager.getInstance(context);
}
```

As you want to return an instance of `? implements MyManager` rather than `MyDefaulManager` specifically.